# Change slideDown to Animate

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I want to change this slideDown effect:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slide').not("#n1").hide();
    $('.slide').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $next = $this.next();
        if (!$next.length) {
            $next = $this.siblings(".slide").first();
        }
        $this.css("z-index","-1"); //make sure $next can slide OVER $this
        $next.slideDown(2000, function () {
            $this.hide().css("z-index","0");
        });
    });
});
```

to this Animate effect:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.slide').not("#n1").hide();
    $('.slide').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var $next = $this.next();
        if (!$next.length) {
            $next = $this.siblings(".slide").first();
        }
        $this.css("z-index","-1"); //make sure $next can slide OVER $this
        $next.animate({marginTop: "400px"}, 2000, function () {
            $this.hide().css("z-index","0");
        });
    });
});
```

The goal is to slide the "next" div down from above the margin to cover the visible div.

```
.slide {height:500px;width:100%;background-color:#f2f2f2;border-bottom:5px solid #f2f2f2;position:absolute;}}

<div id="n1" class="slide" style="display:inline">div one</div>
<div id="n2" class="slide" style="display:block;margin-top:-400px">div two</div>
```

The animate function does not work at all.  Can anyone help fix it?  Am I using animate correctly:  $next.animate({marginTop: "400px"}, 2000, function () {...

Comment: Okay, so what is your question?

Comment: The animate doesn't work at all.  Can anyone recommend a solution?  I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The animate function is working but you can't see it as you have hide it the $next element

```
 $('.slide').not("#n1").hide();
```

The slideDown() method is setting element to:

```
 display="block"
```

and it is animating this element.

In order to achieve similar effect with animate() you will have to show() your element before animation.

Also I presume that you would like to animate $next div to the top of the page so you can set the marginTop value to 0:

```
$next.show().animate({marginTop: 0}, 2000, function () {
      $this.hide().css("z-index","0");
});
```

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lajon/3xcu3urk/2/)

Comment: Question.  The original code is set to "loop" through all divs and reset back to the first.  How would I return old divs to the default -500px margin-top?  I want the effect to loop which requires them all to be reset at some point.

Comment: To reset all divs to margin -500px you could do something like this: `$('.slide').css("margin-top", "-500px")`.